# What is the best way to create a beautiful cover page for Word?

Tags: print-design

I'm actually a computer scientist. I take a course in design right now to improve my skills to create beautiful products once I am out of university.

But I am unexperienced and am just sitting here with design experts only. Now I have an upcoming project. I have completed the project already, but now I have the problem: how to design my document?

I am totally unexperienced. Do you have any programs you would recommend? And how to design a cover page?

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you make your question more specific about what exactly you are trying to design? otherwise someone might close your question as too broad.

Comment: The software is not your problem, i guess, but the idea. Do not try to be original. Find a good model to follow. You are in safe as long as you do not copy images, texts nor brand making color combinations.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a cover for Word, the best program to use is Word.

You need to take into account that if you are preparing a Word document to be delivered that document maintains the editability. So the cover itself should maintain that.

But Word can incorporate a background, and that is a specific element that you then need to combine with Word itself.

---

For your cover, you can look for a free background that suits your content. Perhaps a photo or an abstract image.

And for the styles themselves, look for a style template. There are a lot of them for you to find.

It is very important to remember to use styles, and not add format to the paragraph directly.

---

Design is a profession, it is not an easy task that can be learned just in one week or in a post or tutorial. So to answer the question "how to design" is almost as asking for you to switch careers.

A good option is to find an example of a document you like and try to mimic that document using Word styles.